# Override toString() method java

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I have this in my Main class in java

```
public class Main   {

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "lol";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int aaa=0;
        System.out.println(aaa);
    }
}
```

I Want to Override that toString() Method that implicity called.
why output is 0 not "lol" ?

Comment: `System.out.println(new Main());` will output `lol`.

Comment: There's no instance of the Main class here.  You didn't call that toString method.  You got the one for int

Comment: "_why output is 0 not "lol"_" Becuase you printed an integer, not your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why output is 0 not "lol" ?

because you are printing an integer and not an instance of that `Main class`

you can do the following

```
public class Main   {

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "lol";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // int aaa=0;
        Main myMain = new Main();
        System.out.println(myMain);
    }
}
```

note that you can do

```
System.out.println(myMain);
```

the same as

```
System.out.println(myMain.toString());
```